# Does the sequence $\sin(n!\pi^2)$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the sequence $\sin(n!\pi^2)$ converge or diverge?

Comment: What do you thin? And why?

Comment: As $n$ increases? Did you try with values to see what happens?

Comment: Also, do you think $\pi^2$ is important? Did you try with another value instead?

Comment: If $\pi^2$ were rational, then the sequence would certainly converge to $0$, but as it is, I suspect this may be a hard problem.  I would guess that $\sin(n!\pi^2)$ oscillates erratically with limsup and liminf respectively $1$ and $-1$, but I think proving it might take some work.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Ok, now I feel stupid, I don't see it. Why does $\sin(n!q)$ necessarily converge to 0 for $q \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: I believe this is equivalent to an unknown one, $$ n! \pi - \lfloor n! \pi \rfloor  $$

Comment: @MichaelHardy : I think you forgot a $\pi$ in your reasoning... sinus of an integer is never zero unless you have $\sin(0)$ which is not the case here.

Comment: Converges. Let n>2 . sin(n!π 2 )=sin(2π(n!π/2))=sin(0)  (period of sin  is 2π ). This doesn't work because n!/pi/2 is not an integer. But if this converges to being an integer we are done... Thus, if (iff?) Jagy's expression converges to 0, we have the desired result.

Comment: @JacobWakem : Any reason (or intuition) why it would converge to an integer?

Comment: @user88595 : no; I just believe that is the crux of the problem.

Comment: OK, I should have said if $\pi$ were rational then $\sin(n!\pi^2)$ would converge to $0$.  The point is that if $\pi=a/b$, and $a$ and $b$ are integers, then $n!\pi^2=(n!\pi)\pi$ $=(n!a/b)\pi$, and if $n\ge b$, then $n!/b$ is an integer and so is $n!a/b$, so $(n!a/b)\pi$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$, so that its sine is $0$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I get what you wanted to say but then you have a multiple of $\pi$ which you defined to be rational, sin of it won't be zero. You are splitting $\pi^2$ into $\pi\times\pi$, one you say is a rational, the other one you say isn't...

Answer (score 3):

I devoted a chapter (3) of my [thesis](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~lempp/theses/kumar.pdf) on the set $\displaystyle  G = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sin{(n! \pi x) = 0}\}$. It is easy to see that (Euler's constant) $e \in G$. Let alone $\pi$, I do not even know if $e^2 \in G$.

Answer (score 1):

I cant answer the question but here are some thoughts. $\sin(n \pi^2)$ does not have a limit because $\{ n\pi \}$ is dense in $[0,1]$. So the question would really be is 
$\{ n! \pi \}$ is dense. One might ask if $\{ n! \alpha \}$ is dense for any irrational $\alpha$, but it is easy to see that  $\{ n! e \}\rightarrow 0$ from the series definition of $e$. So $\sin(n! e \pi)$ limits to $0$.
Thus the behaviour of $\{ n! \pi \}$ depends on properties of $\pi$.